# R. Rounding to specific number of digits. No matter of decimal points

Tags: r, rounding

Is it possible to round the number to the desired number of digit dependent on how big the number is?

I get this:

```
x <- c(0.012345, 0.12345, 1.1245, 12.345, 123.45)
round(x, digits = 3)
#[1]   0.012   0.123   1.125  12.345 123.450

signif(x, digits = 3)
#[1]   0.0123   0.1230   1.1200  12.3000 123.0000
```

I want this:

```
#[1]   0.01   0.12   1.12  12.3 123
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that `signif` needs to go inside `round` otherwise 12.345 becomes 12.4.

```
x <- c(0.012345, 0.12345, 1.1245, 12.345, 123.45, 1234.5, 12345, 123450)
x2 <- round(signif(x,3),2)
as.character(x2)
#[1] "0.01"   "0.12"   "1.12"   "12.3"   "123"    "1230"   "12300"  "123000"
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to get you closer to the desired output, but not 100%.

`as.numeric(strtrim(x, 4))`

Or the desired output as string:

```
xl <- strsplit(strtrim(x, 4), "[.]")

unlist(
lapply(xl, function(x) {
paste(x, collapse = ".")
})
)
```